# Parsing unknown data type object Json-like using Python

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am dealing with **Fox news** API and the response is not recognized as a known datatype for me or Python. here is a sample of the response:

```json
// API callback
__jp0({
  "kind": "customsearch#search",
  "url": {
  },
  "queries": {
    "request": [
      {
        "totalResults": "791000",
        "count": 10,
        "startIndex": 1,
        "inputEncoding": "utf8",
        "outputEncoding": "utf8",
        "safe": "off",
        "siteSearch": "foxnews.com",
        "siteSearchFilter": "i"
      }
    ],
    "nextPage": [
      {
        "totalResults": "791000",
        "count": 10,
        "startIndex": 11,
        "inputEncoding": "utf8",
        "outputEncoding": "utf8",
        "safe": "off",
        "siteSearchFilter": "i"
      }
    ]})
```

Here is the API link to see the whole response [Link](https://api.foxnews.com/search/web?q=sport%20-filetype:json%20-filetype:json%20more:pagemap:metatags-prism.section&siteSearch=foxnews.com&siteSearchFilter=i&callback=__jp0)
I want to parse the response as json or any known datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see there in the API is called the [JSONP format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

It's a standard format and so you can just remove parentheses from the response and then load what's inside of parentheses like normal json:

```
data_json = response_json.split("(", 1)[1].strip(")")
parsed_json = json.loads(data_json)
```